# Один метод не начинает выполнение

Tags: php, mvc

День добрый, пока не могу сообразить в чем проблема.
Есть 2 класса, каждый из которых реализует валидацию данных,один именно проверят не является ли поле пустым и т.д, а другой отвечает за правильность ответов в этих полях. Проблема в следующем.

Использую метод класса Validator я как-то так:

```
 $this->validate->validate($_POST,[
  'full_name' => 'isNotEmpty',
  'email' => 'isNotEmpty,isEmail',
]);
```

Первый аргумент имя инпута,второй,имя функции которая будет его проверять.

Все отлично работает, если поле пустое - я получаю ошибку,если нет,все впорядке,но при попытки использовать метод custom, для проверки правильности ответов - первый метод просто игнорируется, он даже не запускается, вообще ничего.

Метод я вызываю, так же

```
 $this->custom->check($_POST, [
  'question_1' => '48',
  'question_2' => 'Алгоритм',
]);
```

Тут то же самое,только второй параметр не функция,а просто значение которое должно совпадать со значением инпута question_1 or 2.

Первый метод,выглядит так:
 [Метод Validate](http://pastebin.com/HNXYZV7C)

Второй метод,выглядит так:

[Метод Check](http://pastebin.com/NBbawZXi)

При вызове одного из них,все работает,при вызове одного за другим - работает только тот,который идет вторым(!), только он.

Выглядит это вот так:

```
 $this->validate->validate($_POST,[
  'full_name' => 'isNotEmpty',
  'group' => 'isNotEmpty',
  'question_1' => 'isNotEmpty',
  'question_2' => 'isNotEmpty',
  'question_3' => 'isNotEmpty'
]);

$this->custom->check($_POST, [
  'question_1' => '3',
  'question_2' => 'Пространственный контиинум',
  'question_3' => '1'
]);
```

Здесь почему-то выполнится custom->check.

Если поменять их местами,выполнится validate->validate.

Может ошибка в какой-то мелочи,но я пока не понимаю в чем она заключается.

Если сделать все методы второго контроллела static, все будет работать.

Вопрос: Почему второй метод вызывается первым,и почему игнорируется первый?

UPD 1.

Нашел ошибку, она в

```
  Session::put('errors', $this->errors);
```

Не очень понимаю,почему,но если убрать эту строчку,и например, var_dump сделать $this->errors, тогда все будет ок. Пока решил костылями,а именно добавил в сессию не errors, a errors_test для теста.

Comment: @arnial, Я же приложил их в посте. Там ссылки на pastebin.

Comment: @arnial, Да,конечно,секунду.

Comment: @arnial, Сорян что так долго - пытался вставить ссылку в области для кода. Сейчас они есть.

Comment: В методе validate, в 26-ой и 33-ей строке в методы для валидации передаются ключи а не данные. Не уверен что ошибка в этом, но это очень странно.

Comment: Можно узнать что сделает метод correct, если до вызова метода check поле было некорректным (из-за validate)? (Возможная ошибка: check не обращает внимания на текущее состояние поля и всегда вызывает методы correct/incorrect)

Comment: @arnial, А он просто добавляет в массив errors ошибку, и в ней указывает что ответ на вопрос %question_1% правильный. 

incorrect добавляет то же самое,только,говорит что неправильный.

Я немного обновил метод validate, он теперь полный. Там вроде,все так и должно быть - я просто в некоторых случаях разбиваю данные через explode, если их больше чем 1.

Comment: @arnial, Просто вконце каждого метода есть проверочка - если errors не пустой,он вызывает редирект с ошибкой. Именно тут я и не понимаю как скипается первый метод..